# How to effectively apply version control for React components at scale?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, version-control, dependency-management

This question is about possible higher-level approaches that one could take to applying version control to React components. Specifically, these components should be more on the "atomic" end of the spectrum, i.e. doing one thing powerfully in a variety of contexts.

Specifically, I'd like your thoughts on versioning such components at scale, whilst addressing issues such as:

- Cross-project usability (i.e. `<Button />` component in both of my React apps);
- Theming (how themes and styles can be shared across these components); and
- Dependencies (e.g. version `1.0.5` of `<StackedButton />` depends on version `2.1.0` of `<Button />`)

I've been looking into [Bitsrc.io](http://bitsrc.io) as a possible tool to help me manage this. I've been largely addressing these issues by having quite a few (~10) Git repositories, each managing a loosely coupled set of components, e.g. `text-components`, `layout-components`, `table-components`, but I feel like I'm at a point, where with the number of components and the dependencies they have, further maintainability may be sacrificed if I make the wrong decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some success using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna); I think it might fit your needs pretty well. You basically would combine all 10 of your repositories in a single one, with each one now being a package within the repository.

Lot of advantages to this approach. Mainly, it lets you still have separate published packages, giving consuming apps flexibility on what they want/don't want to pull in, but it removes a lot of the overhead of having a lot of packages. It becomes much easier to make sweeping changes, and it's impossible for your packages to get out of sync, since they're always updated together. If you make a breaking change in one package that another package relies on, you would fix the package in the same PR as the breaking change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems to me that Lerna requires me to publish my code to npm. I'm currently directly installing each of these repositories inside of my project without publishing to npm; does Lerna support my use case, or would I have to use private npm packages?

Comment: It looks like you can use it and not publish to npm: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/536. Don't have any experience myself doing so.